# codemodule.insertlines break error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using the following to add a sub routine to a module:

```
Public Sub AddInfoProcedure(SubName As String)
Dim VBP As VBProject
Dim VBC As VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As CodeModule

Set VBP = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject
Set VBC = VBP.VBComponents("Reference_Info_Options")
Set CodeMod = VBC.CodeModule
Stop
With CodeMod
    XNum1 = .CountOfLines + 2
    .InsertLines XNum1, "Sub " & SubName & "()" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "End Sub"
End With
Stop

End Sub
```

It runs with no problem in that it does add the sub however at the .insertlines line it breaks and gives the error as below:

> 'Can't Enter break mode at this time' Continue, end etc

Can anyone tell me why it is doing this? or how I can stop the error?

Comment: Tried removing those `Stop` lines? Those try to force it into break mode (and the error refers to it being unable to enter break mode). Are you inserting into the module this sub is in, or into a different module?

Comment: I have removed the stops and it appears to be working fine with a strait run however it does not let me step through to trouble shoot. Not sure why but at least it's working. Thanks

Comment: See [this page](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/vbadebug2010/debug01.php) for how to debug VBA using the built-in IDE. The `Stop` keyword is rarely used, normal breakpoints are used to step through code far more often and don't show this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestions have been helpful. Stepping through the code creates the same issue so it must be something to do with remotely editing modules. It is however working as it should so no need to debug.